# Unhandled NoSuchWindowException when clicking on button

Tags: c#, selenium

This is very simple, I just want to click on a button:

```
// Go back to sign in
Program.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.bestshippers.com");

// Click on the link
Program.driver.FindElement(By.Id("ButtonJoinNow")).Click();
```

However, when I do, I get the following:

> NoSuchWindowException was unhandled, Unable to find element on closed
>   window.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? I don't understand. Could it be because I'm invoking a single driver to perform numerous tasks without closing it before moving to this next task?

Comment: Please show the implementation of `Program.driver`... static field? When do you construct the `IWebDriver`?

Comment: Try this:  `Program.driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#input.ButtonJoinNow.button_loginscreen")).Click();`.  Also, in the code above, you are going to example.com and not bestshippers.com.  Did you mean to do this?

Comment: class Program
{
//setup webDriver
public static IWebDriver driver = new I nternetExplorerDriver(@"E:\Selenium\");

Comment: Unable to find element with css selector == #input.ButtonJoinNow.button_loginscr‌​een 

"I get this when trying to use the cssselector."

Comment: I am creating the web driver in the class containing main, then I'm working in another class when this happens.  I'm going to try to move the code and retest.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their time, I was simply out of scope and didn't know any better.  I restructured and everything seems to be working fine.  I don't know the exact reason but when I constructed the driver in my current class it seemed to be referencing fine via the element ID.